# Android AlertDialog not showing up

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to open an alert dialog within a function. The code just stops running when calling the .show() at the end of my code.
When I'm trying to execute the exact same code snippet in the `onCreate` function of the same class, everything works fine. Why won't the Dialog open, when I'm trying to open it from another function?

```
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = (dialog, which) -> {
        switch (which){
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                //Yes button clicked
                break;

            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                //No button clicked
                break;
        }
    };


    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

    builder.setMessage("Are you sure?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
            .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();
```

Comment: Where do you call that other function? Please post complete function.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, it should be easy:

```
  AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                YourDialogActivity.this).create();

   alertDialog.setTitle("Alert Title");
   alertDialog.setMessage("Alert Message");

   alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "YES clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    });

   alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO",
     new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "NO clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

   alertDialog.show();
```

Please, set how you use that function where it doesn't work for you

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
         AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

    builder.setMessage("Are you sure?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
            .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener);
    AlertDialog alert=builder.create();
    alert.show();
```